# Save and Load Dictionary from encrypted or unreadable or binary format?

Tags: c#, encryption, dictionary, binary, save

I have a dictionary like the follow:

```
public Dictionary<int, SpawnList> spawnEntities = new Dictionary<int, SpawnList>();
```

The class being used is as follow:

```
    public class SpawnList
    {
        public int NpcID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Level { get; set; }
        public int TitleID { get; set; }
        public int StaticID { get; set; }

        public entityType Status { get; set; }

        public int TypeA { get; set; }
        public int TypeB { get; set; }
        public int TypeC { get; set; }

        public int ZoneID { get; set; }
        public int Heading { get; set; }
        public float PosX { get; set; }
        public float PosY { get; set; }
        public float PosZ { get; set; }
    }

/// <summary>Entity type enum.</summary>
public enum entityType
{
    Ally,
    Enemy,
    SummonPet,
    NPC,
    Object,
    Monster,
    Gatherable,
    Unknown
}
```

- How could I save this Dictionary to
  either a binary or encrypted format
  so I could later Load it again into
  my application ?

  **My biggest problem here is not on how to save the file it self or encrypt it but mostly on how to do it when you have a class with it and how you go about deserializing it later.**

My limitation is .Net 3.5 can't use anything higher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way to get you started:

1. Make your class serializable by attaching the `[Serializable]` attribute.
2. Use [`CryptoStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) and [`BinaryFormatter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) to serialize it into a file and encrypt the data.

The reference for `CryptoStream` provides a complete example for setting up encryption and doing the related file handling.

Comment: My biggest doubt here is not really how to save the file or encrypt it but how to do it with the inner class on it and how to deserialize it later ... i was rewritting it while i got all these answers already hehe could you perhaps wrap me an example ?

Comment: @Prix What inner class? Inner classes generally do not pose any problems in respect to (de)serialization. To deserialize “later” also represents no concerns, as long as you maintain the same structure of the class (names, types, and count of properties). However, in the real world data structures change, so you should think about defining your own data format or (better) using something well manageable like XML.

Answer (score 3):

Separate the serialization aspect from the encryption aspect. There are various different ways of serializing the data:

- Write your own serialization code
- Use the built-in binary serializers
- Use the built-in XML serializers
- Use a 3rd party serialization framework such as Thrift or Protocol Buffers

All of these are likely to allow you to serialize and deserialize to/from a stream. Then you should look at using [`CryptoStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream.aspx) to handle the encryption/decryption - but be aware that if your own code needs to be able to decrypt the data with no extra information, then it will need to have the key available to it... which basically means it'll be available to anyone who is able to run the code, too.

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer, basicly i know how to serialize, deserialize etc, but I have never done the process using a class within my object so i was pretty clueless on how could I approach it until.

Answer (score 2):

Mark the class as

```
[Serializable]
```

and serialize it to any Stream using

```
FileStream stream = File.Create("binary.bin");
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
formatter.Serialize(stream, spawnEntities);
stream.Flush();
stream.Close();
```

And Deserialize it using

```
stream = File.Open("binary.bin", FileMode.Open);
spawnEntities = formatter.Deserialize(stream) as Dictionary<int, SpawnList>;
stream.Close();
```